# What's wrong with this wrong derivation of $\ln(-x)$?

Tags: calculus, logarithms

If we take $\ln(x) = \int_{1}^{x} \frac{1}{y} dy$ as the definition of logarithm, then I am ending with a stupid derivation of $\ln(-x)= - \int_{-x}^{-1} \frac{1}{y} dy$.

From the definition, if I go like this: $$\ln(-x) = \int_{1}^{-x} \frac{1}{y} dy = -(\int_{-x}^{1} \frac{1}{y} dy) = \lim_{\epsilon \rightarrow 0} -(\int_{-x}^{-1} \frac{1}{y} dy + \int_{-1}^{-\epsilon} \frac{1}{y} dy + \int_{-\epsilon}^{\epsilon} \frac{1}{y} dy + \int_{\epsilon}^{1} \frac{1}{y} dy)\\ = \lim_{\epsilon \rightarrow 0} -(\int_{-x}^{-1} \frac{1}{y} dy + \int_{-1}^{-\epsilon} \frac{1}{y} dy + \int_{\epsilon}^{1} \frac{1}{y} dy + \int_{-\epsilon}^{\epsilon} \frac{1}{y} dy )  $$ 
[The middle two terms easily cancel,] $ \lim_{\epsilon \rightarrow 0} -(\int_{-x}^{-1} \frac{1}{y} dy + \int_{-\epsilon}^{\epsilon} \frac{1}{y} dy )$, which is probably equal to $ - \int_{-x}^{-1} \frac{1}{y} dy$.

Comment: hmm... did you account that in fact, $\int \frac{dx}{x}=\ln\vert x\vert$? That is the correct expression.

Comment: "probably equal to", so it's not necessary that this shold happen, because as $\epsilon \to 0$, the integral $\int_{-\epsilon}^{\epsilon} \frac{1}{y}dy$ in fact becomes unbounded, so how can you cancel it out of the expression?

Comment: @астонвіллаолофмэллбэрг: This is one of the cases where rigour is needed. Can you rigorously explain why that is unbounded ?

Comment: For rigor, you cannot assume that it is bounded, you must *prove* that it is bounded.

Answer (score 2):

To use the definition you want, you have to be in a world in which you know how to integrate (and presumably differentiate) but don't know about exponentials. Hardy's *Course of Pure Mathematics* chapter IX was like that.  Your definition then makes sense for $x>0$ and defines the logarithm on $(0,\infty)$ and lets you prove a ton of stuff, as in Hardy.

You can't readily use your definition for $x\lt0$ because $\int_1^x dy/y=-\int_x^1 dy/y$ is not defined as a standard Lebesgue integral.  That is because, if it existed, it would be the negative of $(\int_x^0+\int_0^1) \dfrac{dy}{y}$, which is the sum of $-\infty$ (the first integral) and $+\infty$ (the second integral).

Also, I get the impression that $\log -1$ is a number $z$ such that $\exp(z)=-1$, for example $z=i(2n+1)\pi$ for some $n\in\Bbb{Z}$, and my imagination fails to see a way to get complex numbers out of your integral.

It is possible I guess that you don't know why $\int_0^1 dy/y=+\infty$.  This is usually proved by saying that it's $\lim_{a\to0+}\int_a^1 dy/y=\lim_{a\to0+} (\log 1 - \log a)$, but if you really and truly don't know anything about logs, then that's not a good proof for you.  Maybe you know that $\sum_{n=1}^\infty 1/n$ diverges, and can base a proof on that?